# Golang: convert custom type (alias to [32]byte) to string

Tags: go, type-conversion, google-app-engine-golang

This is related to GOLANG language. I can't find out how to convert a value that is of a custom type:

```
type Hash [32]byte
```

into a string representation of that hash:

```
myHash := CreateHash("This is an example text to be hashed")
fmt.Printf("This is the hash: %s", string(myHash))
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

> cannot convert myHash (variable of type Hash) to  string
> compiler(InvalidConversion)

While I'm ok using just [32]bytes, I'd really like to know how to do this in GO; I have been for a while searching and couldn't find a solution this exact case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The statement `type Hash [32]byte` declares a new type, not an [alias](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Alias_declarations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go does not support [conversion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type) from byte array to string, but Go does support conversion from a byte slice to a string. Fix by [slicing](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) the array:

```
fmt.Printf("This is the hash: %s", string(myHash[:]))
```

You can omit the conversion because the `%s` verb supports byte slices:

```
fmt.Printf("This is the hash: %s", myHash[:])
```

If the hash contains binary data instead of printable characters, then consider printing the hexadecimal encoding of the hash with the `%x` verb:

```
fmt.Printf("This is the hash: %x", myHash[:])
```